# Azure Google Authentication shows Error:disallowed_useragent

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, google-oauth, azure-mobile-services

I encountered this error quite recently [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCNyN.png)

I think it's due to this change in Google Oauth: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html.

I'm using Azure Authentication service to authenticate my iOS application written in Xamarin Forms (C#).

The code requests Azure Authentication service:

```
var window = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var root = window.RootViewController;
if(root != null)
{
    var current = root;
    while(current.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        current = current.PresentedViewController;
    }

    var user = await AzureService.Instance.Client.LoginAsync(window.RootViewController, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "access_type", "offline" } });
    return user;
}
```

The URL request is:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    const string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?alt=json&suppress_webview_warning=true";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);
    var json = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserProfile>(json);
    return profile;
}
```

However it still shows me the error:
The Azure authentication for Google is setup correctly as I have been using this setup for over a month until recently. Anyone got the same problem or any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue and all the advice I'm getting is written in native iOS code. I'm dealing with a traditional Ruby on Rails app with JS and HTML on the front-end. I'm not doing OAuth with JS. I'm anything with Ruby but I think this change basically killed my standalone app.

Answer (score 4):

The short version is that Google changed the OAuth protocol to be "more secure".  We are currently working on updates to the various client SDKs to enable the new more secure method, which affects server-flow only.

The short version of what to do is to implement client-flow.  Integrate the Google SDK into your app and then send that received token to the backend.  Since you are in Xamarin.Forms, this will mean implementing something in the platform-specific code.

Sorry, I don't have an example of this.  I have done FB auth and AAD auth, but not Google auth at this point.  The concepts are the same, however.  You need to do Google Auth in your platform specific code, then call the ZUMO auth endpoint using something akin to this:

```
public async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(MobileServiceClient client)
{
    // Call the code to do the Google Auth via the Google SDK
    var accessToken = await LoginGoogleAsync();
    // Construct and call the client-flow ZUMO auth
    var zumoPayload = new JObject();
    zumoPayload["access_token"] = accessToken;
    return await client.LoginAsync("google", zumoPayload);
}
```

The next release of each Azure Mobile Apps SDK will include the Google OAuth changes.  I don't have a timeline for those releases, unfortunately.

Comment: In Google blog they said that we can add "suppress_webview_warning=true" into request URL to temporarily avoid the error but I'm not sure if I added it to the correct place. For the codes that you posted, what's inside LoginGoogleAsync function?

Comment: The LoginGoogleAsync() method is the call to trigger the Google SDK authentication.  You have to implement Google Auth via their Client SDK in that method and return the access token that you receive back.

Comment: We are working on it.  I'm expecting the iOS SDK to be out in beta this week, but we are still working on it.

Comment: Hi @AdrianHall any updates on this? We saw that the client sdk has been updated to 3.1.0 (for .Net) but it seems that the changelog has not yet updated. Does this contain the fix for the Google Sign In? https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Yes - .NET and iOS Native have been updated.  Android Native is still being worked (due to complexities in the Android platform).

Comment: I'm no longer at Microsoft, so I don't have visibility into their release timeline.  That being said, .NET relies on Xamarin.Auth and would need to be integrated.  It shouldn't be a hard job to do, assuming Xamarin.Auth supports the right thing.